# Open the gw address in the browser using cmd

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm looking for a command to open the default gateway address in the browser.

This command will display the default gateway address:

```
ipconfig | findstr "Default Gateway"
```

I guess the following command should take part of the output (the address) and and define it as a variable in the following command:

```
start http://<address>
```

But I'm ignorant of the cmd syntax so I don't know how to proceed...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command store the default gateway in `X` variable which can be used later commands:

```
For /F "tokens=13 delims= " %X in ('ipconfig ^| find "Default Gateway"') do echo %X
```

To use this in a batch file, replace `%X` with `%%X`. In that line, the `for` command takes the 13th token (separated by a space) from `ipconfig | find "Default Gateway"` command output and stores it in `X` variable. The caret sign (`^`) is used to treat pipe symbol (`|`) as a normal character.

The option details can be found with `for /?` command. For online version, read here https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html.

Comment: Thanks for your response,
In summary, this will be the command:
For /F "tokens=13 delims= " %X in ('ipconfig ^| find "Default Gateway"') do start http://%X